# Need pattern for a complex Regex Split

Tags: c#, .net, regex, tokenize, lexer

I'd like to split the following string

```
// Comments
KeyA : SomeType { SubKey : SubValue } KeyB:'This\'s a string'
KeyC : [ 1 2 3 ] // array value
```

into

```
KeyA
:
SomeType
{ SubKey : SubValue }
KeyB
:
This's a string
KeyC
:
[ 1 2 3 ]
```

(: and blank spaces are the delimiters although : is kept in the result; comments are ignored; no splitting between {}, [], or '')

Can I achieve that with Regex Split or Match? If so, what would be the right pattern? Comments to the pattern string would be appreciated.

Moreover, it's also desirable to throw exception or return an error message if the input string is not valid (see the comment below).

Thanks.

Comment: What would happen to the input `"A{B[C}D]"`? To `"A'B{C'"`? To `"A{B{C}D}E"`?

Comment: For the first one, it should return an error (preferably with some context for debugging). For the second one, it should return

    A , {B{C}D} , E

Comment: Is there a reason you're forcing this to be a regular expression? This would be much (much!) easier to write as a recursive descent parser.

Comment: I initially thought that it could be achieved with a not-so-complicated Regex pattern. However, I've implemented a custom Lexer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern...

```
string pattern = @"(\w+)\s*:\s*((?>[^\w\s\"'{[:]+|\w+\b(?!\s*:)|\s(?!\w+\s*:|$)|\[[^]]*]|{[^}]*}|\"(?>[^\"\\]|\\.)*\"|'(?>[^'\\]|\\.)*')+)\s*";
```

... in two ways:

1. with Match method which will give you what you are looking for with keys in group 1 and values in group 2
2. with Split method, but you must remove all the empty results.

How is build the second part (after the `:`) of the pattern?

The idea is to avoid, first at all, problematic characters: `[^\w\s\"'{[:]+`
Then you allow each of these characters but in a specific situation:

- `\w+\b(?!\s*:)` a word that is not the key
- `\s(?!\w+\s*:|$)` spaces that are not at the end of the value (to trim them)
- `\[[^]]*]` content surrounded by square brackets
- `{[^}]*}` the same with curly brackets
- `"(?>[^"\\]|\\\\|\\.)*"` content between double quotes (with escaped double quotes allowed)
- `'(?>[^'\\]|\\\\|\\.)*'` the same with single quotes

Note that the problem with colon inside brackets or quotes is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for when you get to KeyC.  How do you know when the string value for KeyB ends and the string for KeyC begins?  Is there a colon after 'this\'s is a string' or a line break?  Here's a sample to get you started:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void SplitString()
{
    string splitMe = "KeyA : SubComponent { SubKey : SubValue } KeyB:This's is a string";
    string pattern = "^(.*):(.*)({.*})(.*):(.*)";

    Match match = Regex.Match(splitMe, pattern);

    Assert.IsTrue(match.Success);
    Assert.AreEqual(6, match.Groups.Count); // 1st group is the entire match
    Assert.AreEqual("KeyA", match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
    Assert.AreEqual("SubComponent", match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
    Assert.AreEqual("{ SubKey : SubValue }", match.Groups[3].Value.Trim());
    Assert.AreEqual("KeyB", match.Groups[4].Value.Trim());
    Assert.AreEqual("This's is a string", match.Groups[5].Value.Trim());
}
```

Comment: The ^ character denotes the start of a line, and the parentheses define the groups.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Both ':' and blank spaces are delimiters. I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 0):

this Regex pattern should work for you

```
\s*:\s*(?![^\[]*\])(?![^{]*})(?=(([^"]*"[^"]*){2})*$|[^"]+$)
```

when replaced with

```
\n$0\n
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?3689p)